# How to resolve heteroskedasticity in Multiple Linear Regression in R

Tags: r, validation, data-science, linear-regression

I'm modelling multiple linear regression. I used the bptest function to test for heteroscedasticity. The result was significant at less than 0.05.

How can I resolve the issue of heteroscedasticity?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different type of linear regression

**Ordinary Least Squares (OLS)** for homoscedasticity.

**Weighted Least Squares (WLS)** for heteroscedasticity without correlated errors.

**Generalized Least Squares (GLS)** for heteroscedasticity with correlated errors.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, Arun.

Personally, I don't think heteroskedasticity is something you "solve". Rather, it's something you need to *allow for* in your model.

You haven't given us any of your data, so let's assume that the variance of your residuals increases with the magnitude of your predictor.  Typically a simplistic approach to handling it is to transform the data so that the variance is constant. One way of doing this might be to log-transform your data.  That might give you a more constant variance.  But it also transforms your model.  Your errors are no longer IID.

Alternatively, you might have two groups of observarions that you want to compare with a t-test, bit the variance in one group is larger than in the other.  That's a different sot of heteroskedasticity.  There are variants of the standard "pooled variance" t-test that might handle that.

I realise this isn't an answer to your question in the conventional sense.  I would have made it a comment, but I knew before I started that I'd need more words than a comment would let me have.